# Power BI - DateTime list - many to many query merge

Tags: datetime, merge, powerbi, m

Let's imagine you have 2 tables:

1. Data table with Start, End and ID columns (IDs are distinct).

Start,End,ID 
2020-01-01 00:01:00,2020-01-01 00:01:05,1111-1111111-1111-11-11
2020-01-01 00:01:00,2020-01-01 00:05:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:02:00,2020-01-01 00:03:05,1111-1111111-1111-11-13
2020-01-01 00:10:00,2020-01-01 00:11:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-14

2. DataTime table with a list created with List.DateTimes(#datetime(2020, 01, 01, 00, 01, 0), 10, #duration(0, 0, 1, 0))

2020-01-01 00:01:00
2020-01-01 00:02:00
2020-01-01 00:03:00
2020-01-01 00:04:00
2020-01-01 00:05:00
2020-01-01 00:06:00
2020-01-01 00:07:00
2020-01-01 00:08:00
2020-01-01 00:09:00
2020-01-01 00:10:00

I want to merge those tables on the M query level so there is 1 line for each ID if the Start is bigger or equal to the DateTime from the second table, and End is smaller or equal to the DateTime from the second table. Expected result:

DateItme, ID
2020-01-01 00:01:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-11
2020-01-01 00:01:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:02:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:03:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:04:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:05:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:06:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-12
2020-01-01 00:02:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-13
2020-01-01 00:03:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-13
2020-01-01 00:06:00
2020-01-01 00:07:00
2020-01-01 00:08:00
2020-01-01 00:09:00
2020-01-01 00:10:00,1111-1111111-1111-11-14

Please help :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can by made by M language; We need to add 1 as "dummy" column

My Query1 (Date table)

```
    let
        Source = List.DateTimes(#datetime(2020, 01, 01, 00, 01, 0), 10, #duration(0, 0, 1, 0)),
        #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "dummy", each 1),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"dummy", type text}})
    in
        #"Changed Type"
```

And my Table definition:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("jY6xCQAxDANXeVzHIDmfJqsE77/GG5JShBdCxRWH1rJAwMHqA0xwAtYEHUVZce74mapl++kZm2pPKE9IT7/96cJDKA95+/Na5gc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Start = _t, End = _t, ID = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start", type datetime}, {"End", type datetime}, {"ID", type text}}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "dummy", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([ID], "1", 1), type text),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Inserted Text Before Delimiter", {"dummy"}, Query1, {"dummy"}, "Query1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each let mydate= [Start] , mydate2 = [End] in 
Table.SelectRows([Query1],each [Date] <= mydate2 and [Date] >= mydate)),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Date", "dummy"}, {"Custom.Date", "Custom.dummy"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Query1"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

The most important line is this one:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each let mydate= [Start] , mydate2 = [End] in 
Table.SelectRows([Query1],each [Date] <= mydate2 and [Date] >= mydate))
```

[image]

Comment: Genius! I'll let you know once I check it :)